# Add markers on the brand name like all starbucks near by without passing latitude, longitude

Tags: android, google-maps, geocoding, reverse, marker

I have bit idea about reverse geocoding, I can fetch the json or xml response by calling url like this
http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=starbucks
and then by fetching lat, long in for loop we can add markers, but I need markers on startbucks just by passing url, Is there any provision?

Comment: yupp, i got it, List<Address> result = new Geocoder(getActivity()).getFromLocationName("KFC,Pune", 3); In address parameter we can give any company name. but I have one more doubt, here on the address of KFC/ Startbucks I want to show infowindow having address lines, phone number, website link, facebook link for that comapany name, is google play service have any method to return me this all info? or I have to call url for google map?